# Logical error in a C++ selection sort algorithm?

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting, logic

I'm brand new to C++ and am trying to write this simple selection sort function. Apologies if the answer is simple to the more experienced coders, but I am beginner and have been staring at this for a long time to no avail. Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
using namespace std;
array<int, 10> unsorted {3, 4, 1, 5, 7, 2, 8, 9, 6, 0};

void printarray(array<int, 10> arr) {
    int count = 0;
    for (int i : arr) {
        if (count < arr.size()-1) {
            cout << i << ", ";
        } else {
            cout << i << endl;
        }
        count++;
    };
}

int selection_sort(array<int, 10> arr) {
    int test;
    array<int, 10> newarr;
    for(int j = 0; j < arr.size(); j++) {
        test = arr[j];
        for(int i = j; i < arr.size(); i++) {
            if(arr[i+1] < test) {
                test = arr[i];
            }
        }
        newarr[j] = test;
    }
    printarray(newarr);
    return 0;
}


int main() {
    selection_sort(unsorted);
    return 0;
}
```

When I run this function it prints an int array containing 10 zeros. Is there an error with the way I am assigning values to the array (in C++), or rather is there a problem with the logic itself?

Comment: It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming. Further reading: [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and [Debugging Guide](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/)

Comment: What are the values in `arr`? If the smallest value is at the end of `arr` it will be copied into every element

Comment: In addition to NathanOliver's suggestion about debugging, we need a [mcve] to answer your questions. This should include a `main()` function that illustrates how you call the `selection_sort()` function.

Comment: @AlanBirtles As a matter of fact the last value is a zero! the values of arr are {3, 4, 1, 5, 7, 2, 8, 9, 6, 0}. That absolutely makes sense now, I see the logical error there, thanks!

Comment: @NathanOliver Thanks for that, I will read over those pages and start using a debugger right away

Comment: Some Bad at `if(arr[i+1] < test)`. When `i` reaches its maximum value of `arr.size()` - 1, `arr[i+1] ` will be out of bounds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both of the implementations are wrong. I just corrected @Adrisui3's answer.
Correct solution:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{   
    vector<int> array(5);
    int aux;

    array[0] = 10;
    array[1] = 2;
    array[2] = 45;
    array[3] = -5;
    array[4] = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < array.size(); i++)
    {
        int min = i;
        for(int j = i+1; j < array.size(); j++)
        {
            if(array[j] < array[min])
            {
                min = j;

            }
        }

        if (i != min)
        {
            aux = array[i];
            array[i] = array[min] ;
            array[min] = aux;
        }
    }
    for(int k = 0; k < array.size(); k++)
    {
        std::cout << array[k] << std::endl;
    }

}
```

Reference : [wikipidia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sort)

Answer (score 1):

That's quite a strange way to implement Selection Sort. You've made several mistakes there, as far as I can see. First of all, you can't use arr.size() in the first for loop, as it would cause the second one to just go off the limits, which causes unexpected behaviour. If by chance those were regular arrays you'd get a nice segmentation fault. Even though you don't get a run-time error, that's something you need to be aware of.
On the other hand, the main problem here is caused by the way in which you are using indexes, as well as the fact that you don't really need a second array.

Here you have an example of this algorithm.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{   
    vector<int> array(5);
    int aux;

    array[0]=10;
    array[1]=2;
    array[2]=45;
    array[3]=-5;
    array[4]=0;

    for(int i=0; i<array.size()-1; i++)
    {
        for(int j=i+1; j<array.size(); j++)
        {
            if(array[j]<array[i])
            {
                aux=array[j];
                array[j]=array[i];
                array[i]=aux;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Aditionally, I'd recommend you to use vector instead of array, both are STL's containers, but vector is way more flexible and useful, although it consumes some extra memory.

I hope my answer was clarifying enough. I'm here if you need any extra help. Good luck!

Comment: Hey! You're right, vector consumes more memory! My bad, sorry.